# prove that linear span of an orthonormal set M of a hilbert space is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

prove that linear span of an orthonormal set M of a Hilbert space is closed

I think i need a convergent seq in M and show that the limit belongs to span of M. but could not do it.

Comment: This isn't true if by "linear span", you mean the set of linear combinations of finitely many elements of $M$ (as is the convention).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove that, because it is false unless the orthonormal set is finite.

Every finite dimensional subspace of a normed space is closed, so the finite case does not depend on orthonormality.

For every infinite orthonormal set, there is a countably infinite subset $(e_1,e_2,\ldots)$, and you can show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k}e_k$ is in the Hilbert space, not in the linear span of the orthonormal set, but in the closure of the linear span of the orthonormal set.